# X11 bad access at first try but working on successive tries

Tags: xorg, x11, socket

I use the following setup to forward `X11` output from my local machine to the server. I will outline the setup:

1. `X11` server and the client are on the same local machine.
2. The `X11` server runs on my local machine `A`.
3. The client runs on my local machine as a docker container and is called `B`.
4. I try to forward graphical output from a program (`R`) on the client `B` to the server on host `A`.

Here is how the access works:

- My client `B` has read access to `/tmp/.X11-unix`. Hence, it has access to the unix domain socket `unix:0`.
- I allow access to this socket to the client `B` by issuing `xhost +si:localuser:$(USER)` on the host `A`. (Which is a server interpreted address which grants access to a single local user.)

All of this works as expected BUT whenever I try to access the socket the first try is not working and I get the error `X11 protocol error: BadAccess (attempt to access private resource denied)`. When I close the `X11` graphics device again and reopen it everything works. The problem persists even when I use a totally different setup that relies on `ssh`-based `X11-forwarding`. I could trace the problem back to the `cairo` device if I use a `Xlib` device access is successful at first try.
Does anyone have experience with programs that access the `X11` server's unix domain socket with a `cairo` device or has any kind of idea why this is happening?

Comment: maybe `~/.Xauth` is stale and gets removed or truncated the first time. It's  something like that anyway, I expect - the problem is not the failed first try most likely, but the last successful session's sloppy exit.

Comment: I assume by `~/.Xauth` you mean the `~/.Xauthority` file. No such file is ever created (I checked just now.) as I don't rely on `xauth` based authentication. The really strange thing is that using a `Xlib` graphics device will run without any problems but a `cairo` based does not. (I'm still searching the depths of the web for hints. :))

Comment: much luck. look in the `/var/log/Xorg.log.[num]` files and possibly in the paths specified by `$XDG_CONFIG_DIRS`,  `$XDG_DATA_DIRS`, `$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR`

Comment: Please post the command-lines you're using for the server and the client.

Comment: I use `bash` as default shell/cli and `xterm` as terminal emulator.

Comment: I'm fairly certain that this has something to do with `Xlib` vs. `XCB`. `dwm` uses `Xlib` and not `XCB`. `Cairo` has `XCB` support enabled per default (but should also support `Xlib` as this is now usually run on top of `XCB`). It came to my mind that this is an `Xlib` vs. `XCB` issue when I used my other window manager `i3` where this problem does not occur.