# Some GTk3 applications aborting with BadAccess when DISPLAY=:0 but not DISPLAY=hnam.local:0 or even DISPLAY=unix:0

Tags: x11, error-handling, privileges, gtk3

I've had some issues with my XQuartz environment not starting due to a bit of a freak reason that was a rather hard to figure out. It's (mostly) working again but I must have caused another regression during my various troubleshooting attempts.

Applications like epiphany, gtk3-demo-application and even `zenity --calendar` used to start just as you'd expect. Now, they abort because of a BadAccess that apparently occurs through the `XCreatePixmap` call under `gdk_x11_window_set_icon_list`. Strange, because I don't see that as a possible error for XCreatePixmap.

Even stranger: it does **not** happen if I start these applications with `DISPLAY=hnam.local:0` (or even `unix:0`!) rather than just `DISPLAY=:0`. From what I know this makes the connection go through the TCP/IP stack. Acceptable as a workaround as the performance/functionality loss is probably moot under XQuartz but I'd still like to understand what's up here.

I'm suspecting that it's got something to do with the fact that I did use the `privileged_startx` wrapper that is normally enabled for XQuartz users and is responsible for setting up the directories under /tmp. I disabled that years ago for reasons I cannot recall, but re-enabled during my troubleshooting. It's disabled again, and since I did that there's another strange phenomenon. I can start the offending applications like before just after launching my X11 environment. A couple of minutes later they will again throw a BadAccess on start. Or maybe I can start them just once which will trigger whatever causes the BadAccess on subsequent starts. EDIT: but see below *)

I had X11 configured (and hopefully have, again) to allow connections from remote servers in my LAN. I also always do a `xhost +x` because there's no reason for any tighter form of connection control.

During my troubleshooting I also caused a brief issue with my .Xauthority file (got owned by root), which I fixed by re-owning it and running `xauth -b`.

Do the above symptoms ring any bells? Could they be related to what's in those directories under /tmp or to something fishy in my .Xauthority file? It seems rather weird that operations would violate rules when performed from the most local kind of connection but not from remote connections, no?

Thanks!

EDIT:
I have a hunch of the direct reason, but still no explanation why this has started happening.

My X11 session is "anchored" by an xfce4-panel. It looks like the offending XCreatePixmap call might be targetting a drawable that's owned by that panel process, e.g. to install the application icon in the panel's "window button". It would make sense to do this only if the 2 XDisplay strings are identical. That could explain why I can also avoid the error with DISPLAY=unix:0 (AFAIK that's equivalent to DISPLAY=:0).

As I said, I still can't fathom why this worked before, and even less why it now works for a limited amount of time. EDIT: it also seems I misinterpreted what xwininfo showed me.

I've cobbled together an `XIOErrorExitHandler` that checks an env. variable to know it an attempt should be made to continue. That seems to work.

EDIT: running e.g. `sudo zenity --calendar` also doesn't throw a BadAccess which again points in the direction of a file that no longer has the correct permissions.

*) EDIT: and the weirdest observation of all: there is in fact no actual delay; the time aspect was introduced by me postponing one of my usual operations: moving the initial terminal windows to the desired screen (if it's attached) and height-maximising them via the WM (xfwm4).
Changing the height of 1 of these 2 windows (belonging to separate Konsole5 instances) triggers the issue *and it goes away if I restore that window's initial height*. If I close the window the trigger action moves to the other window.

Annoyingly I cannot find any indication what `request_code 133` stands for.

Comment: This looks a lot like https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/151884/70384 in that the offending gdk function also seems to use Cairo.

Comment: Not really an answer as to the underlying reasons, but the problem did go away after I quit Xquartz, cleaned out everything X-related under /tmp and restarted XQuartz. It was thus indeed most likely a feature aka intended behaviour, the question remains why.

Comment: Actually, the problem went away for a bit longer than a few minutes, but came back just the same, grrr!

Answer (score 0):

This is not really a definitive answer but it has to be a beginning of one:

I had a look at exactly what happens in Qt's XCB plugin (v 5.9.8). As I thought, it falls back to using regular memory for the window backingstore if no shared memory can be obtained, but it still tries to get at the MIT-SHM extension in that case. I've tweaked the code a bit so that attempt isn't even made but that did evidently not have any effect.

I also finally had the reflex to see if the shared memory limitations could be increased. Lo and behold, increasing `shmseg` (from 8 to 16, and `shmall`) made the shm allocation work. "Retro-actively" to already running applications too (evidently) ... and *that* caused the BadAccess error to disappear even with the "offending" window height-maximised.

I don't see how a `shmget` failure in another app could cause an X11 error in a completely unrelated application. But the X11 server probably calls `shmget` or equivalent also, and those calls might fail for the same reason they failed in my Qt applications. A bit strange that those would be reported as BadAccess but who knows, maybe some code downstream from a failed allocation reports on receiving a null pointer.